# Exit Vim External Command Line Shell

Tags: linux, shell, vim, command-line

I accidentally put ping 8.8.8.8 in the Vim External Command Line Shell by executing
:! ping 8.8.8.8
Now the command won't stop and I am not able to return to my file editing buffer in Vim. When I press Ctrl+Z it suspends the entire vim process and takes me back to Linux Shell. Is there any way to suspend/kill the Vim Shell subprocess in case it goes into some kind of infinite execution and return back to Vim buffer ?

Comment: Open another terminal, and run `pkill -9 ping` if Ctrl+C on the current one didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Type "Ctrl + c" and ENTER or RETURN twice.
Also try: `:!ping -c3 8.8.8.8`
( -c stands for 'count' and 3 do it 3 times and exit )
...for a windows style behavior of ping.